# Adding a prefix to a value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called EMP_SAL which has 2 columns EID number(7), SAL number(4).

EID column values: 100,101,102

SAL column values: 1000,2000,3000

I want to update the table so that the values in the EID column are displayed like ENO.100,ENO.101,ENO.102 instead of showing 100,101,102.

Comment: Why? Do you really want the `ENO.` prefix on every row in the table permanently, or do you just want it for display? Why is the EID column a varchar at the moment if it contains numbers? If you do want it to include the prefix then the column isn't wide enough - you'd need to increase the size to accommodate it.

Comment: Sorry, EID datatype is number(7)

Comment: You still haven't clarified if you're actually updating the table, or just want the prefix in the result set. You can't put a string prefix into the actual table column though.

Comment: You can use computed column. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx

Comment: @AlexPoole I want to update the table and EID datatype is number(7)

Comment: @JoeMalpass: your statement is invalid. SQL uses `||` to concatenate strings (not `+`) and so does Oracle.

Comment: @GSazheniuk The question is about Oracle, not SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is No. You cannot put characters in a number column. You should redesign your table and make the EID column varchar2 in order to put characters there.

The update would be simple:

```
Update EMP set EID='ENO.'||EID;
```

Comment: Thank u very much @FlorinGhita

Comment: If the EID column datatype is changed to varchar2 then                               we also use this syntax                                                                          UPDATE EMP_SAL SET EID = LPAD(EID,7,'ENO.');